# Is there a Java way to format an array output by removing the curly brackets around each key-value pair?

Tags: java

My code works OK by returning the expected key-value pair output from an sql query, however the formatting of the output needs to be changed. I tried removing the curly brackets around each key-value pair contained in the array, but I couldnt succeed with that.

This is what I have tried, but it didn't work:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getDemoNames() {
    List<Map<String, String>> demoNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object result : resultList) {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) result;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String key = String.valueOf(row[0]).trim().replaceAll("[{}]", ""); //I tried removing the curly bracket this way
        String value = String.valueOf(row[1]).trim().replaceAll("[{}]", "");
        map.put(key, value);
        demoNames.add(map);
    
        System.out.println(demoNames);
    }
    return demoNames;
}
```

Output: `[{001=DEMO}, {002=APPLE}, {003=GOOGLE}, {004=ALAMANCE COUNTY}]`

What I want is to get the output in this format:

```
[{001=DEMO, 002=APPLE, 003=GOOGLE, 004=ALAMANCE COUNTY}]
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: *Output:...* Output by doing what?

Comment: Is this output by printing the list of maps you create? I'm a bit confused!

Comment: What you have created is a list of maps with each map containing one element.  And you are trying to make it *look like* a list containing a single map.  Why don't you just *create it* as a list containing a single map containing all of the entriers?  Or am I missing something ...

Comment: Yes, printing the elements in the array. I have added a print statement

Comment: @StephenC please demonstrate your suggetion in an answer box for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List of Maps to single Map via streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490314/convert-list-of-maps-to-single-map-via-streams). Just change the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42520687/721855 to return a List or add the resulting Map to a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a Map returned, not a *List* of Maps:

```
public Map<String, String> getDemoNames() {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Object result : resultList) {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) result;
        String key = String.valueOf(row[0]);
        String value = String.valueOf(row[1]);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    // Consider printing from the call point instead to keep this code clean
    System.out.println(map);
    return map;
}
```

Using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` iterates over its entries in insertion order, so calling its `toString()` will render in the same order as `resultList`.

Consider storing objects of a class with appropirately named String fields in `resultList` instead of `Object[]`, which would make your code less brittle and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of maps with each map only having a single entry (because the map is created inside the loop and then added to the list).

There are at least three options to get the output in the format you request:

1. Populate your data structure in the expected layout in the first place. Meaning that you have a list with a single map (and the map contains all the entries). *Presumably, this is the solution which you actually want:* Create the map outside the loop, then populate it from within the loop (each loop iteration puts an entry into the map).
2. Manually build the output string:

   ```
   boolean first = true;
   final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("[{");
   for (final Map<String, String> map : demoNames) {
     for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       if (!first) sb.append(", ");
       first = false;
       sb.append(entry.getKey()).append('=').append(entry.getValue());
     }
   }
   sb.append("}]");
   System.out.println(sb);
   ```
3. Transform the map into the expected format, then use `toString` on the map:

   ```
   final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   for (final Map<String, String> demoName : demoNames) {
     map.putAll(demoName);
   }
   System.out.println(map);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  It seems like your real problem is generating output that looks a certain way, and you have picked the wrong intermediate data structure.  Now you are trying to compensate for the wrong choice with some clever transformation of the `toString()` output from the data structure to get your desired output.

If you have no knowledge of what is in the map's key / value pairs, then using `replaceAll` to remove unwanted brackets is fragile.

But I think the problem is deeper than that.  You are creating a list of maps where each map contains one element, but you are trying to make it *look* like a list containing a single (combined) map.  So ... why not create it as a single map?

```
    public List<Map<String, String>> getDemoNames() {
        List<Map<String, String>> demoNames = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Object result : resultList) {
            Object[] row = (Object[]) result;

            // The following removes braces from the key and
            // value strings.  This is unnecessary ... unless
            // you are expecting such stuff in the result list.
            String key = String.valueOf(row[0]).trim().replaceAll("[{}]", ""); 
            String value = String.valueOf(row[1]).trim().replaceAll("[{}]", "");

            map.put(key, value);
        }
        demoNames.add(map);
        System.out.println(demoNames);
        return demoNames;
    }
```

Furthermore, there isn't any obvious reason to have the list here.  It doesn't appear to serve any purpose.  (Except maybe to preserve the order of the key-value pairs.  And the `LinkedHashMap` preserves that.)

---

On the other hand ... if you really do need to generate a list of maps, then the best way to format that data as you want would be iterate the maps using `for` loops or streams.  See @knittl's answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try it this way too:

```
String output = getDemoNames().stream().
    flatMap(m ->m.entrySet().stream()).
    map(e ->e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue()).
    collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[{", "}]"));
System.out.println(output);
```